# Is there a way to configure rspec to abort remaining specs on first fail?

Tags: rspec, guard, spork

I'm running the specs under spork and guard, which complicates matters. But this would be very handy.

Comment: Did you try [Fail Fast](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/configuration/fail-fast)?

Comment: That's it!  New in rspec 2.1 and I didn't notice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fail Fast, as answered in the comments.